# HTML email - change font sizes gmail

Tags: html-email, google-schemas

I am coding HTML emails and would like to change the font size on mobile. I have used the code that google used as a text but changed it a bit and added font size. Below is the code that I tested. The color changed but the font size did not. Any hints or ideas where I might find an answer?

Thank you in advance for the help, it is muchly appreciated.
Vince

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
      #body {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width:500px) {
        .colored {
          color:red;
        }
        p {
          font-size: 10px;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='body'>
      <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
      <p class='colored'>
        This text is red if the window width is
        below 500px and blue otherwise.
      </p>
      <p>Jerry</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to change the size? HTML in email is very restrictive. Have you tried an inline style?

Comment: I have tried inline, but would like to change the size on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

You may just need to add the `!important` flag.

```
p {
  font-size: 10px!important;
}
```